# Enchant a weapon using /give command in Minecraft Bedrock/PE

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Minecraft /give command
I want to enchant a weapon via commands.

I tried doing `/give @p Diamond_Sword 1 0 {ench:[{id:16,lvl:2}]}`

But I get this error

*missing '}' or member name on line 1 column 2*